# Pass Values Between aspx webpage and class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I am wondering how to call a Label from a certain aspx page in another cs file. For example:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Test1.Insert1(this);
    }
```

This code i have in the Something.aspx.cs file to call a method from another cs file i created which looks like:

```
public static class Test1 
{
    public static void Insert1(System.Web.UI.Page Ins)

     {
        string conn = "Data Source=pc-...";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conn);
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                Ins.LabelAdd.Text = "Worked!";
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand myCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ... ", sqlConn);
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Ins.LabelAdd.Text = "Error! " + ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. I was able to do this before with a session but this won't work. I can't call the LabelAdd which I used in the Something.aspx page. Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thank you.

Comment: I think you should pass in the values as parameters to the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your control Reference like...

```
public static void Insert1(Label lblId)
```

also please add this  `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;` in your class

Comment: Works, I had the using implemented already, but I didn't think of adding the labelId there. Thank you.