# passing values between separate classes

Tags: c#, class, static-members

I have two separate classes: 1 In a tbIndexUI.aspx.cs page and the other in a regular.cs class file.
I would like to pass two data members from the regular .cs class file to the .aspx page, however every time the "Page_Load" method fires it resets all the values that were previously passed. I tried commenting out everything in "Page_Load" and I event went as far as removing the method all together, but the parameter values are still being reset.

Is there a way to pass these values to and maintain them? Any examples would be extremely helpful as I am lost. I looked at this [[example]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867259/pass-values-between-aspx-webpage-and-class) but was unsuccessful.

Code for my aspx.cs page

```
public partial class tbIndexUI : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private int _numOfCols = 0;
    private int itemsPerCol = 0;

    public int numColumns
    {
        set
        {
            _numOfCols = value;
        }
    }

    public int itemsPerColumn
    {
        set
        {
            _itemsPerCol = value;
        }
    }
    public static void passData(int numOfCol, int itemsPerCol)
    {
        numColumns = numOfCol;
        itemsPerColumn = itemsPerCol;
    }
 }
```

Code for my regular class process.cs

```
void sendInformation()
{
    tbIndexUI.passData(numOfCols, itemsPerCol);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class tbIndexUI : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public int numColumns
    {
        set
        {
            ViewState["numOfCols"] = value;
        }
    }

    public int itemsPerColumn
    {
        set
        {
            ViewState["itemsPerCol"] = value;
        }
    }
    public static void passData(int numOfCol, int itemsPerCol)
    {
        numColumns = numOfCol;
        itemsPerColumn = itemsPerCol;
    }

    //when you need to use the stored values
    int _numOfCols = ViewState["numOfCols"] ;
    int itemsPerCol = ViewState["itemsPerCol"] ;
 }
```

I recommend that you read the following guide about the different ways that you can persist data between pages and page loads

**http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31344/Beginner-s-Guide-To-View-State**

Comment: Mauricio, I tried using the ViewState that you showed in your example but the values do not hold. When I step through the code the values are being declared properly, but the moment it enters into the aspx.cs page the Viewstates are reset to null. Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Do not have your class library classes have instances of web page classes. You want the opposite, you want your .aspx page/controls to have instances of classes in your "regular" .cs files, because that makes them reusable across multiple pages.

The way your posted code is written, the `sendInformation` method cannot be used with any other web page, because it is hard-coded to use the `tbIndexUI` control.

Instead, you want to have an instance of whatever the class name (you do not indicate that in your posted code) is that has the `sendInformation` method in it. Doing it this way allows for the class to hold the `numOfCols` and `itemsPerCol` values and expose them to the web page/control via properties.

Instead you could write this:

```
public class TheClassThatHoldsNumOfColsAndItemsPerCol
{
    public int NumOfCols { get; set; }
    public int ItemsPerCol { get; set; }

    // Method(s) here that set the values above
}
```

Now in your aspx code, you have an instance of `TheClassThatHoldsNumOfColsAndItemsPerCol` and anytime you store that instance in `Session` cache or `ViewState` so it can persist across page postbacks.